# PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Could not connect to the Selenium RC server

Tags: selenium, terminal, phpunit, yii, command-line-interface

I using PHPUnit and Selenium Server to testing Yii Application, but whenever i tried it always give me this error.

here is the code on my terminal

```
GusDeCooL:tests budiarsana$ phpunit functional/SiteTest.php
PHPUnit 3.5.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.

EEE

Time: 04:31, Memory: 8.50Mb

There were 3 errors:

1) SiteTest::testIndex
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Could not connect to the Selenium RC server.

/Users/budiarsana/host/yii/1.1.8/test/CWebTestCase.php:61

2) SiteTest::testContact
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Could not connect to the Selenium RC server.

/Users/budiarsana/host/yii/1.1.8/test/CWebTestCase.php:61

3) SiteTest::testLoginLogout
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Could not connect to the Selenium RC server.

/Users/budiarsana/host/yii/1.1.8/test/CWebTestCase.php:61

FAILURES!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 0, Errors: 3.
```

How can this happen?
The selenium is opened my firefox, but notting happen on my firefox and i get that error.
I tried using PHPUnit only to testing some code using NetBeans IDE it working correctly (the testing is without use Selenium)

If there is any information needed to make my question clear please inform.

**Workstation:**
MAC OSX LION 10.7.2
PHP Version 5.2.17
PHPUnit 3.5.15 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Comment: did you start the selenium server from command line?

Comment: yes i did start the selenium server from the beginning with this code `java -jar selenium-server.jar`. or do i need add `sudo` command?

Comment: What version of selenium server are you using. Try using latest version.

Comment: @GirishB in the first i use 2.8, now i update it to GirishB and its all work @_@

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem Solved, i update my Selenium Server and its working correctly.